# Cannot get maven project.version property in a Spring application with @Value

Tags: maven, spring-boot

How to get the maven project.version property in a Spring Boot application with a @Value annotation?

Answer (score 158, accepted):

After some research and trials on how to get the Maven project version in a SpringBoot application I couldn't find anything working for me.

Using a manifest is definitively a rotten path due to class loaders issues, i.e. one gets the first manifest Spring finds, which in my case was not the one of my application.

One solution I have found is to use the maven resources plugin to "filter" (replace) properties in resource files. In this case the Spring `application.properties`.

Below are the steps to make this work.

In the pom file, activate resources filtering with the following definition:

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>application.properties</include>
        </includes>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

In the `application.properties` file:

```
application.name=@project.artifactId@
build.version=@project.version@
build.timestamp=@timestamp@
```

**Notice the @property@ instead of ${property}.** in the `application.properties` file.

The `spring-boot-starter-parent` pom redefines the standard `${}` delimiter as `@`:

```
<resource.delimiter>@</resource.delimiter>
<!-- delimiter that doesn't clash with Spring ${} placeholders -->
<delimiters>
    <delimiter>${resource.delimiter}</delimiter>
</delimiters>
```

One can then access those properties in Spring using `@Value` like this:

```
@Value("${application.name}")
private String applicationName;

@Value("${build.version}")
private String buildVersion;

@Value("${build.timestamp}")
private String buildTimestamp;
```

[A sample project is available here](https://bitbucket.org/JackG/maven-properties-at-runtime).

Comment: You basically solved what Spring documentation describes for it: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html

The one point in the docs is if you use the Spring Boot parent you don't need to explicitly define the resource filter.

Comment: We don't use spring-boot-starter-parent, but we didn't need to add the delimiters config like your answer and [section 72.1.1](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html) says.

Comment: The timestamp should actually be something like `build.timestamp=@maven.build.timestamp@`.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to do this using yaml ? I'm trying to escape the '@' characters using quotes around the values (i.e "@project.artifactId@" but in Cent-OS the properties are not being resolved when I run the app as a jar

Comment: I was still struggeling although I had this section in my pom. The problem was, that I had a separate `application.yml` in test/resources. When you want to enable filtering for that one, too, you'll need a `testResources` section similar to the one mentioned in http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html

Comment: For newbies like me, I was trying to get the build number using JUnit test case which was not running the spring app. For you to get the build number run the app first.

Comment: Just define "info.app.version=@project.version@" and the information will be available at http://localhost:8080/actuator/info : nothing more to do! See https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-info-actuator-custom

Comment: I used this solution and it works when I run my application on my computer but after deploying my application it doesn't work and it returns something like @project.artifactId@ that I added in application.properties.

Comment: I have been using the `@project.name@` to get the name from pom.xml `<name>myapi</name>`.  However, I find that it works most of the time but every once in a while it does not resolve project name but stays as `@project.name` causing my tests to fail.  I have not been able to find solution to it.

Answer (score 81):

To get access to Maven properties in *Spring Boot application* all we need is map them with delimiter `@` in the `application.properties` like this:

```
app.version=@project.version@
app.name=@project.name@
```

Then use them in the app like ordinary properties, for example:

```
@Service
public class SomeService {

   @Value("${app.version}")
   private String appVersion;

   // other stuff
}
```

Source: [Automatic Property Expansion Using Maven](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html#howto-automatic-expansion-maven)

But if you are using **yaml** to store application properties, you may need to replace delimiter `@` with some other one, for example `^` in our `pom.xml`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.7</version>
    <configuration>
        <delimiters>
            <delimiter>^</delimiter>
        </delimiters>
        <useDefaultDelimiters>false</useDefaultDelimiters>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Or even simpler - just replace variable `resource.delimiter` in `propeties` block of your pom.xml:

```
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <resource.delimiter>^</resource.delimiter>
</properties>
```

Then use it in your property file, for example:

```
app:
  version: ^project.version^
  name: ^project.name^
```

Comment: Why we need to change the delimiter for the YML

Comment: @PrabhatYadav Often the default one doesn't work in YAML

Comment: FYI for anyone looking for this, unless we replace `@` sign with `^`, Spring Cloud Config Server cannot serve YAML files with these delimiters properly.

Comment: @emrekgn those placeholders are suppose to be replaced at build time, they shouldn’t be there anymore when Spring Cloud Config Server serves the yaml files.

Comment: Actually, when there is a native profile, the config server resolves YAML files when requested, not during build time. That's why Cepr0's suggestion to replace them with another char is the correct way to go because `@` sign is not a valid char. But, in all other use cases, you are correct.

Answer (score 72):

There a easier way to do this, don't need to add application.properties or delimiter changes.

***for Spring Boot 2.X.X***

Simply add plugin with goal build-info and Autowire start up class with bean BuildProperties.

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
   <executions>
     <execution>
       <goals>
         <goal>build-info</goal>
       </goals>
     </execution>
   </executions>
</plugin>
```

Startup class will have

```
@Autowired
  BuildProperties buildProperties;
```

later in `@PostConstruct` in start up class you can call multiple methods to retrieve build **Timestamp**, **Version**, **Name of Artifact**, **Group** etc.

```java
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(YourSpringApplication.class);

@Autowired
BuildProperties buildProperties;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(YourSpringApplication.class, args);
  }

@PostConstruct
  private void logVersion() {
    LOGGER.info(buildProperties.getName());
    LOGGER.info(buildProperties.getVersion());
    LOGGER.info(buildProperties.get("time"));
    LOGGER.info(buildProperties.getGroup());
}
```

The `info` actuator will automatically use, and display this information if it detects it, as well as display [git information](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.10.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-application-info-git) if it finds any.

Comment: This is the most cleaner answer. @MilanDesai thank you very much!

Comment: With SpringBoot 1.5.1 there us no such bean:
`Consider revisiting the conditions above or defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.info.BuildProperties' in your configuration.`

Comment: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.info.BuildProperties' available:

Comment: For 'Failed Autowired of BuildProperties' just run a 'mvn clean package' and then restart the spring boot application from either Eclipse/IntelliJ.

Comment: doesn't work in Spring Boot 3

Comment: Thanks @SledgeHammer I will check the update the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

It works with `@` charactor.

```
<resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    <filtering>true</filtering>
</resource>
```

and...in your application.properties or appplication.yml file....

```
version: @project.version@
name: @project.name@
```

Comment: Yes ! That's the simplest solution (I use Spring Boot 2.7.6).

Answer (score 2):

It's probably because your main pom doesn't declare spring-boot-starter-parent as its parent pom.
Because when so, the filtering is done by default, without needing to declare the filtering explicitly

For me changing from :

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>mycompany-parent</artifactId>
    <version>20</version>
</parent>
```

to :

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

In my application main pom.xml fixed the issue without having to declare the filtering.

Answer (score 0):

As I was using `spring-boot-starter-parent` I just had to use double quotes with `@` as the delimiter in the my `application.yml` in order to grab the version:

```
app:
  version: "@project.version@"
```

I then get the value later with `@Value`:

```
@Value("${app.version}")
private String appVersion;
```

The Spring docs use double quotes as the example [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.properties-and-configuration.expand-properties.maven) when using an `application.yml` instead of an `application.properties`.

I did not need to modify delimiters this way in the pom.