# Display build timestamp in Spring Boot actuator info endpoint

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot-actuator

I am using the Spring Boot actuator to get my application's info.

I have added the Spring Boot actuator dependency in my pom.xml, and added below lines in my property file:

```
info:
   app:
     name: @project.name@
     description: @project.description@
     version: @project.version@
```

I get the values: name, description and version of my project from pom.xml. I also want to get build time and display it on the `/info` endpoint.

Any suggestions?

Should I also Change my pom.xml file for it?
I tried using :

```
info.app.build-time=@build-time@
```

But this doesnt work.

Thanks

Comment: You don't have to use those settings in application.yml "anymore" see https://stackoverflow.com/a/55395807/32453

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can define a `timestamp` Maven property in your pom.xml like so:

```
<properties>
   <timestamp>${maven.build.timestamp}</timestamp>
   <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm</maven.build.timestamp.format>
</properties>
```

And then reference it using the `@...@` convention like so:

```
info:
   app:
     timestamp: @timestamp@
```

Comment: Is it also possible to find which profiles are active from pom using actuator?

Comment: Are wondering whether you can add something to your `info` endpoint which tells you which profile was active when the application was built? If so, you can set a property in your profile and then reference that property in the same way as you already reference timestamp, name, version etc.

Comment: Yes, to know active Profile when application was built. Would try it. thx

Comment: I wonder, why only 'timestamp' is working. I tried other names but it's not resolved. https://stackoverflow.com/a/77361613

Answer (score 2):

Spring Boot (1.5.10.RELEASE or 2.0.0.RELEASE) supports this using the actuator-starter with the help of some simple gradle/maven adoption now.

You can add [git commit information](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.10.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-application-info-git) as well as [build information](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.10.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-application-info-build) and customize them to some extend.