# Actuator info endpoint displays number instead of readable build time

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I try to display a build time in actuator's info endpoint.

I added a [spring-boot-maven-plugin](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.10.RELEASE/maven-plugin/examples/build-info.html) plugin to `pom.xml`:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>build-info</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

The output is

```
"build":{"artifact":"client-manager","name":"client-manager","time":1698242102.345000000,"version":"1.0.16-SNAPSHOT","group":"com.company"}
```

while jar's META-INF/build-info.properties contains:

```
build.time=2023-10-25T14\:54\:05.717Z
```

The time property is hard to read and I would favor something I can read. I tried to add a date format into `time` property in plugin's configuration section, but maven failed on `Instant` parsing it as a value.

Other questions deals with it by exposing custom env in the info actuator endpoint: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46363030/1639556. I think there must be some way to tell Actuator to format the build time more friendly. And I am surprised it's not a default preference.

Comment: A couple of questions:

1. What version of spring-boot are you using? 
2. Does your application code create its own `ObjectMapper` bean?
3. Can you share your `application.yml` or `application.properties` file? I'm curious if there's a setting for something like `spring.jackson.date-format` that's altering how dates are serialized by Jackson

Comment: Spring boot 2.7.16. I set DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false) only. We consume other artifacts, so they may override other properties which is out of my scope.

Comment: Can you try hitting the `/actuator/beans` endpoint and see where the beans of type `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper` are coming from? When I use start.spring.io to generate a project, I don't get the behavior you're seeing (the date is formatted in a friendly ISO8601 format). The only way I've been able to reproduce what you see is by defining my own `ObjectMapper` bean and registering the `JavaTimeModule` module

Comment: I also threw together a quick reproducer project to demonstrate the default behavior from spring-boot, as well as the effect having a custom `ObjectMapper` bean has on overriding the default behavior: https://github.com/billkoch/so-77360825

Comment: It comes from my Configuration annotated class. So it seems to my local issue.

Comment: I realized that other microservices display the human readable format. I removed my definition of ObjectMapper. But the actuator still displays the number instead of date. How can I identify which dependency overwrites a default configuratio? Is there any way?

Comment: When you removed your definition of the `ObjectMapper` bean, does `/actuator/beans` now show the ObjectMapper coming from spring-boot's autoconfiguration? LIkely JacksonAutoConfiguration: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration.java#L130

Comment: It looks so "resource": "class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperConfiguration.class]"