# Maven property in application.yaml not resolved

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I started with this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46363030/1639556) to add a build time to actuator. It works well, when property is named `timestamp`. But I would like something more specific, so I picked up `build.timestamp`. I am struggling making it work.

pom.xml:

```
<build.timestamp>${maven.build.timestamp}</build.timestamp>
```

application.yaml:

```
built: '@build.timestamp@'
```

/actuator/info endpoint, the property is not resolved:

```
"built":"@build.timestamp@"
```

Then no quotes:

```
built: @build.timestamp@
```

Spring does not even start, as stated here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59393137/1639556

```
2023-10-25 18:24:09.036 [ERROR][restartedMain]{} o.s.b.SpringApplication: Application run failed
org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerException: while scanning for the next token
found character '@' that cannot start any token. (Do not use @ for indentation)
```

I even tried `build-timestamp`, no luck. What's the proper variant? This is the only working variant:

```
<timestamp>${maven.build.timestamp}</timestamp>
timestamp: @timestamp@
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just need to edit your pom.xml file, and add to the properties tag:

```
<properties>
   <build.timestamp>${maven.build.timestamp}</build.timestamp>
   <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm</maven.build.timestamp.format>
</properties>
```

and also solve the `<build.timestamp>` placeholder using the `<resources>` tag into the `<build>` tag:

```
  <build>
  ...
  <resources>
    <resource>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>application.yaml</include>
        </includes>
    </resource>
  </resources>
  ...
  </build>
```

as it is commented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38983935/7431162).

Comment: Thanks, I will try next morning. But I am surprised, why @timestamp@ works without filtering.