# Display Build time in spring boot /info endpoint

Tags: maven, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I have the below properties configured in my spring boot application.yml

```
info:
  app:
    name: @project.artifactId@
    description: @project.description@
    version: @project.version@
    timestamp: @timestamp@
```

After adding Spring Boot Actuator dependency, I am able to access `/info` endpoint and view the information.

To display the **timestamp** information, I add the below property in maven project's pom.xml as below,

```
<properties>
   <timestamp>${maven.build.timestamp}</timestamp>
    <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'</maven.build.timestamp.format>
</properties>
```

The timestamp is displalyed in correct format but it is not correct one. I mean I am in IST timezone and the value is displayed as,
timestamp: "2017-10-03T16:24:02Z" which is incorrect, probably it is displaying in GMT time format. But, I want IST format.

Can someone help me on this?

Comment: answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38983934/cannot-get-maven-project-version-property-in-a-spring-application-with-value/55395807#55395807) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38983934/cannot-get-maven-project-version-property-in-a-spring-application-with-value/55395807#55395807 you are not required to have it retrieved it from application.properties/yml spring is smart enough to take care of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Maven emits the `maven.build.timestamp` in UTC.

You can use the `timestamp-property` goal of the [Maven Build Helper Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html) to emit a timestamp in a different timezone.

Here's an example:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>timestamp-property</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>timestamp-property</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <name>build.timestamp.with.offset</name>
                <pattern>yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'</pattern>
                <timeZone>IST</timeZone>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I've just run a build with that plugin in place and with the properties defined in your question and I'm echo'ing the values of both the `timestamp` property and the `build.timestamp.with.offset` property:

```
[INFO] Executing tasks
     [echo] [timestamp]: 2017-10-04T08:14:58Z
     [echo] [build.timestamp.with.offset]: 2017-10-04T12:44:59Z
```

This clearly shows that the default timestamp is in UTC and the `build.timestamp.with.offset` is in IST.

So, you could use this plugin and then update your `application.yaml` to use the `build.timestamp.with.offset` property.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to auto-detect the timezone and generate the data in the current timezone format.

Comment: @all4u: not that I'm aware of. Looking at the [code](https://github.com/mojohaus/build-helper-maven-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/codehaus/mojo/buildhelper/TimestampPropertyMojo.java) it seems to default to GMT unless you supply a value. You could [fork the plugin](https://github.com/mojohaus/build-helper-maven-plugin) and change the behaviour of the `timestamp-property` to meet your requirements.