# @project.version@ cannot be found in the remote application.properties

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I need to get project version from maven pom file. Before I did configs with SPRING_CONFIG_ADDITIONAL-LOCATION parameter everething was fine. Now I cant get project version from application.properties (version = @project.version@), its value is "@project.version@". Why I cant get real value anymore?

Comment: Look into Maven Ressource Filterfing https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html

Comment: @Zorglube For filtering param requeried resourse directory, but I cant use it, because my configs set dynamically with SPRING_CONFIG_ADDITIONAL-LOCATION

Comment: Did you try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51419158/3981539 ?

Comment: @KavithaKarunakaran I cant use that example. Its not a problem with the delimiter and as I said, I cant use solutions with strict <directory> parameter

Comment: what was the target for spring.config.additional.location? is the .properties file which contains project.version still available in classpath?

Comment: @KavithaKarunakaran New location for target is /opt/application/application.properties Properties file still available, but should be removed soon