# How can I integrate POM build version into YAML generation using springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin?

Tags: spring-boot, pom.xml, openapi, springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin

Is there a way to programmatically set the build version from the POM of my Spring Boot application into the OpenApi YAML generated by the springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin?

How can I achieve it?

Currently I have integrated the springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin this way:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>integration-test</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>generate</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <apiDocsUrl>http://localhost:9090/v3/api-docs.yaml</apiDocsUrl>
            <outputFileName>my_open_api_specification.yml</outputFileName>
            <outputDir>${project.build.directory}/my_open_api_specification/</outputDir>
            <skip>false</skip>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

I have an interface to annotate methods with OpenApi annotations:

```
@Tag(name = "API Operationen")
@RequestMapping
public interface RestApi {
...

    @Bean
    default OpenAPI myOpenApi() {
    
        return new OpenAPI()
            .info(new Info()
                .title("The title")
                .version("1.0")           <-- I want to dynamically set this version with the value coming from  BuildProperties (POM version).
                .description("The description"));
    }
}
```

I found some information using spring-boot-maven-plugin but I didn't succeed:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <!-- <version>2.5.4</version> -->
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>build-info</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        </executions>
</plugin>
```

---

### Update

---

In the meantime I moved the bean definition from the interface into a @Configuration file/class but when I start the application I get a NullPointerException  during the bean creation of `myOpenApi`:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan("xxx")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class OpenApiConfig {

    @Autowired    // <-- was missing
    BuildProperties buildProperties;

    @Bean
    OpenAPI myOpenApi() {

        return new OpenAPI()
            .info(new Info()
                .title("FooBar")
                .version(buildProperties.getVersion())
                .description("blablabla"));
    }
}
```

As far as I understood the BuildProperties gets created by the Maven plugin and is available when the `myOpenApi` is going to be created, but it seems as if this is not the case. (At least with my configuration.)

Comment: Not sure how you create that bean in an interface, but you may follow [Cannot get maven project.version property in a Spring application with @Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38983934/cannot-get-maven-project-version-property-in-a-spring-application-with-value) to inject the build version by `@Value` and then set to `.version()`

Comment: I didn't have any success with this attempt.

Comment: You need to add @Autowired to `BuildProperties buildProperties`.

Comment: OK, that did the trick. Thumb up! I thought by using @RequiredArgsConstructor this would be implicitly done as it works with controllers, ...? 
Post it as an answer, if you want, that I can rate it adequately. :-)

Comment: If you want to make use of @RequiredArgsConstructor, you should make `BuildProperties buildProperties` final.